# realgcc.exe: error: \build\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes-tmp\Main.o: No such file or directory

Tags: haskell

I am trying to set up a simple project so I can learn haskell, well, learn it from the ground up to get a better understanding of the theoretical concepts underpinning it. I do however seem to get this error when trying to build it using cabal.

I was trying to build it and was expecting the default main file for cabal to work.

[My file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL5yC.png)

```hs
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, Haskell!"
```

I am using ghc version 8.10.7

I am running the following commands:

cabal init

cabal build

and then I get the error on the build command/

The full error:

Build profile: -w ghc-9.2.5 -O1

In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):

- Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes-0.1.0.0 (exe:Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes) (first run)

Preprocessing executable 'Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes' for Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes-0.1.0.0..

Building executable 'Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes' for Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes-0.1.0.0..

Linking C:\Users\beren\source\repos\Graham Hutton Haskell Excersizes\dist-newstyle\build\x86_64-windows\ghc-9.2.5\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes-0.1.0.0\x\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes\build\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes.exe ...

realgcc.exe: error: C:\Users\beren\source\repos\Graham Hutton Haskell Excersizes\dist-newstyle\build\x86_64-windows\ghc-9.2.5\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes-0.1.0.0\x\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes\build\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes\Graham-Hutton-Haskell-Excersizes-tmp\Main.o: No such file or directory
`gcc.exe' failed in phase` Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

edit:

https://github.com/bacdekker/haskell-excersizes

Comment: Please, provide _in the body_ of the question all of the following: which command are you running?, what's the whole error? (don't use the title for this) and which project you try to build? (if you can, don't use a photo. Better a git repo or something easier to check)

Comment: I used cabal build and then cabal init. That's basically how all the files were created. I did a clean install and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: And the error is just that? could you copy paste the whole output? It is very difficult to understand the problem with only partial information.

Comment: added the full error message and a link to github

Comment: you github link is just a file with git attributes... nothing that can help.

Comment: I fI have to guess, I'd say is a problem with gcc, which has nothing to do with haskell. Be sure you have the latest version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after checking/installing/updating gcc it ended up working after I made a new project in a different directory.